# Changing django default pk with AutoField to BigAutoField

Tags: django, django-models, primary-key

My model has a default pk with AutoField (integer) but later on i discovered that i need to use BigAutoField instead! 
And also i have data in then with other models referencing the student model:: how do i change the pk field to BigAutoField and also reflects on other referencing models

```
class Student(models.Model):
    matric_no = models.CharField(max_length=20,  unique=True)  # first set it to U(random)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, null=True)
    programme = models.ForeignKey(Programme, null=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, null=True)
    course_comb = models.ForeignKey(CourseComb, null=True)
    serial = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    current_level = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, default='100', null=True)
    last_login = models.DateField(null=True)
    is_active = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=1, choices=((1, 1), (0, 0)))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

a model referencing Student

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    student = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attachment = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Profile Image")
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, verbose_name="Surname")
    othernames = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, verbose_name="Othernames")
    SEX_CHOICES = (
      ("M", "Male"),
      ("F", "Female")
    )
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set `primary_key=True` in the field definition:

```
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

If you want to use this in multiple models you could also make an abstract model and let others inherit it:

```
class BigPkAbstract(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And in your other models:

```
class SomeModel(BigPkAbstract):
    <your model here>
```

‌

Comment: thanks for your response!!!

i have a referencing model like this

`class Profile(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: @FestusFashola that is fine, the `OneToOneField` shouldn't have a problem with it.

Comment: @FestusFashola if there is a problem (which I don't think there will be) you might need to add some logic to your migrations.

Comment: @FestusFashola and are you in production yet or just using test data?

Comment: Everything is in place !!!
did a makemigrations and migrated the files....
all the referencing tables has been adjusted accordingly!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148022/discussion-between-festus-fashola-and-the-cthulhu-kid).

Comment: Would you need to modify ManyToManyField or ForeignKey fields linking back to an object with a BigAutoInt primary key?

Comment: @dogoncouch You shouldn't need to do anything but if something were to come up you could likely alter the migrations to sort it.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Making migrations to change id to BigAutoField failed for me, because of the relationships. I can't recall the exact error. I've looked through the field types available (django 2.0), and there isn't anything like BigForeignKey or BigManyToManyField. I guess that means you'd have to edit the migrations by hand at this point.

Comment: @dogoncouch I don't want to clog up the comments here. Send me a message on LinkedIn or Twitter?